# How can I Make automated routes using python?

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel sheet that has 3 columns, unique ID, Latitude, and Longitude.
And I want to make routes from these IDs. And each route contains 10 IDs and doesn't exceed a specific distance.
Can I automate these routes using python or anything instead of making them manually?

Comment: @Without any data or example, I would be considering the Solver.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.